# How do you set different attributes for different MagicMock instances in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, patch, magicmock

I'd like to assert that `say_name` was called with each value in the list `name`.

```
from unittest.mock import patch


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


def say_name(name):
    print('My name is ' + name)


def my_func():
    names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    objects = [MyClass(name) for name in names]
    [say_name(object.name) for object in objects]


@patch('my_test.say_name', spec_set=True)
@patch('my_test.MyClass', spec_set=True)
def test_my_func(mock_my_class, mock_say_name):
    names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
    my_func()
    [mock_my_class.assert_any_call(name) for name in names]
    # [mock_say_name.assert_any_call(x.name) for x in xs]
```

If only one instance of `MyClass` was created, as is usually the case, I could set the attribute by setting `mock_my_class.return_value = PropertyMock(name=name)`.

However, in this case, multiple different instances of `MyClass` are created.

Thus, this code will throw an error because `my_func` is executed by the tester, `say_name` is being passed a mock with no `name` attribute.

Therefore, how can I set different attributes for different MagicMock instances?

Comment: @wim I'm using py.test to run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use [`side_effect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to sequentially return values from a mock:

```
>>> from unittest.mock import Mock
>>> m = Mock()
>>> m.side_effect = ['spam', 123, 'potato']
>>> m()
'spam'
>>> m()
123
>>> m()
'potato'
```

Applying to your use-case:

```
from types import SimpleNamespace
from unittest.mock import call, patch

from my_lib import my_func


@patch('my_lib.say_name')
@patch('my_lib.MyClass')
def test_my_func(mock_my_class, mock_say_name):

    class FakeObj:
        pass

    obj1 = FakeObj()
    obj1.name = 'foo'
    obj2 = FakeObj()
    obj2.name = 'bar'
    obj3 = FakeObj()
    obj3.name = 'baz'

    mock_my_class.side_effect = [obj1, obj2, obj3]
    my_func()
    assert mock_my_class.call_args_list == [call('foo'), call('bar'), call('baz')]
    assert mock_say_name.call_args_list == [call('foo'), call('bar'), call('baz')]
```